# Deallocate part of array in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

Say I have an array of numbers on device (CUDA), something like

```
float *d_x;
cudaMalloc(&x, N*sizeof(float));
```

Where `x` will be something like `[0,0,3,0,3,0,3,1,5,1,0]`.

I am performing two operations on the array. The details are unimportant, but the first operation will act as a sort of preprocessing, permuting the values of `x` and returning an index, and the second will perform some operation only on the first `n` values of the array, where `n` is the value returned by the first operation.

My problem is that the second operation is computationally much much more expensive by nature and will take much more time, while only really touching the first `n` values of the array.

So, something like

```
uint operation1(float* d_x)
{
    // call some kernel and wait for the kernel to execute.
    // The kernel reorders x into [3,3,1,5,1,0,0,0,0,0]
    return n; // n in this case is 5, because there are 5 nonzero values in d_x
}
void operation2(float* d_x, int n)
{
    // call another kernel, sorting the subarray [3,3,1,5,1], and never touching the values at index
    // n or above
    // In other words, sort the subarray of values *d_x, *(d_x + 1), ... *(d_x + n - 1) to get
    // [1,1,3,3,5]
}

int main()
{
    float* d_x;
    // fill d_x with input data
    int n = operation1(d_x);
    // many many lines of code doing several other things with it.
    operation2(d_x, n);
    // more code.
}
```

My question is twofold:

1. Is it a good idea to deallocate the part of the array that will no longer be used after `operation1`?
2. If yes, what is the safest and cleanest way to go about this?

Comment: Depends on the context. If you only have that one kernel running on the GPU and you have exclusive access to it, having that stuff in memory shouldn't make any difference. If there are other users or other Kernels running on a different stream, you might want to free the space. But the amount of memory that is allocated generally doesn't have any influence on you performance. Only the amount of loads in the kernel is relevant.

Comment: @Paul In my case, running out of memory is a serious concern, and there are other kernels also running on the GPU at the same time. Being able too free seems like a good idea, so long as it's safe.

Comment: That being said, I don't know of any feature in CUDA (or C/C++ generally) which allows changing the size of an existing allocation. You can only allocate another array of size n and copy the relevant entries into that one before freeing the first array. This might be problematic when the first vector already is using most of the memory such that you don't have space for another n elements.

Comment: If the first operation is that cheap, maybe consider doing it on the CPU? I mean if the input data of the first function is already output from another kernel this is naturally **not** a good option.

Comment: @Paul The input can come from either source, but will probably come from another kernel in the future.

Comment: If the Input comes from a kernel (meaning it is already on the device), I would just leave it as is. You could have a CPU version of the first function to use when the input resides in main memory, such that you also have a smaller memcpy.

Comment: You cannot partially deallocate or resize an allocation in CUDA.  Your only option is to copy the desired data to a new allocation, and free the old allocation entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to deallocate the part of the array that will no longer be used after operation1?

It is not so much a "good" idea as a completely unsupported one. There is no realloc style operation in the CUDA APIs, and given the cost and synchronous nature of memory allocation on GPUs, not a good idea from a performance perspective, even if there was such a thing (or your own equivalent allocation-copy-free implementation).

> If yes, what is the safest and cleanest way to go about this?

See above.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thank you for the answer.